# Queueing system using Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, chat

So I've been trying to make a queueing system for an omegle clone.
Here, there is an empty "queue" dict. Whenever there is post request, i.e someone clicked on the CHAT button, one of 2 things can happen.

(1) If the queue dictionary is empty, create a random code, create a new item in queue, and save the info via sessions. After that, display a waiting screen (waiting.html). And check in a While loop if there are 2 members, in that case, redirect to /chat.

(2) If the queue dictionary is NOT empty, the code will be the first item in the dictionary's key, which is a random 4 digit code, append your name in the member's list of the item, and save all the stuff via sessions.
After that, if the number of members (len(members_list)) is 2, then redirect to /chat

Here's the code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room, emit, SocketIO
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "verrriii_Sekretttt_kIeyeee__:DDDD"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

queue = {}


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    session.clear()
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        favColor = request.form.get("favColor")
        submit = request.form.get("submit", False)

        #check if there is all the information
        if not name:
            return render_template("home.html",
                                   error="GIVE MOTHERLAND OUR NAME, COMRADE!",
                                   name=name)

        if favColor == "select":
            return render_template(
                "home.html",
                error="GIVE MOTHERLAND YOUR COLOR OF CHOICE, COMRADE!",
                name=name)

        #on submitting / on post request
        code = "".join(random.choices(ascii_uppercase, k=4))

        #the important part
        if len(queue) == 0:
            queue[code] = {"members": [name]}
        
            session["name"] = name
            session["favColor"] = favColor
            session["code"] = code

            while len(queue[code]["members"]) == 1:
                return render_template("waiting.html")
            else:
                return redirect(url_for("chat"))
    
        else:
            code = next(iter(queue))
            queue[code]["members"].append(name)
    
            session["name"] = name
            session["favColor"] = favColor
            session["code"] = code
    
            if len(queue[code]["members"]) == 2:
                return redirect(url_for("chat"))

            else:
                return render_template("waiting.html")

    return render_template("home.html")

#This part is not required for the question
@app.route('/chat', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chat():
    name = session.get("name")
    favColor = session.get("favColor")
    code = session.get("code")

    if name is None or code is None or favColor is None or code not in queue:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))

    return render_template("chat.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=81, debug=True)
```

base.html (use it as a base for other docs, by injecting them into base.html via jenga)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico')}}"> -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@700;900&family=Rubik+Mono+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/50ee6035c0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

home.html (home page):

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title>Omwegle • Soviet Omegle</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="branding">
        <h1 class="logo">OM<span class="red">WE</span>GLE</h1>
        <h5 class="slogan">Soviet Omegle</h5>
        <h5 class="slogan">Коммунизм будет процветать!</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="info">
                <h5 class="label">TELL MOTHERLAND ABOUT <span class="red">WE</span></h5>
                <input type="text" class="name" value="{{name}}" name="name" placeholder="Tell Motherland our Name">
                <select name="favColor" id="favColor">
                    <option value="select">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="#ff0000">Soviet Red</option>
                    <option value="#ff2400">Stalin Red</option>
                    <option value="#ffd800">Soviet Yellow</option>
                    <option value="#ffc40c">Stalin Yellow</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">SPEAK WITH FELLOW COMRADES</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    {% if error %}
    <div class="errors">
        <h2 class="errors_text">{{error}}</h2>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

waiting.html (waiting page):

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title>Omwegle • Soviet Omegle</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="branding">
        <h1 class="logo">OM<span class="red">WE</span>GLE</h1>
        <h5 class="slogan">Soviet Omegle</h5>
        <h5 class="slogan">Коммунизм будет процветать!</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="loading">SEARCHING FOR FELLOW COMRADES...</h1>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Right now, my chat.html is just a blank page.

First to check if the number of members are 2, I used an IF statement in the if len(queue) == 0: block.
Later when it didn't work, i used the while loop. ITS STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Most of these variables are undefined.

Comment: @ggorlen do I share my entire "/" route where all of my variables are defined? If so, I did edit my question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share the HTML files too, and preferably a requirements.txt?

Comment: @ggorlen Alright. I've added the HTML files, and for the requirements, just install flask and flask-socketio, I've myself haven't installed anything as I'm using an online editor - replit.com, which sets up the env and auto installs everything for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not clear what the question/problem/desired behavior is, though. What's the issue here? "Later when it didn't work, i used the while loop. ITS STILL NOT WORKING" -- what's [not working](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen This is a queuing system
In my system, there is an empty dictionary, called, "queues".
When someone sends a post request, i.e, they clicked on the "chat button" in the home page, One of 2 things are supposed to happen.
(1) If the dictionary is empty (your the first person) u create an item in the dictionary with the a generated code and list of all the members and redirect if the number of members in that item hits 2. The problem im facing is in checking the number of members in the 1st case
(2) If it is not empty, u just join the code corresponding to the first item & redirect.

Comment: Sorry if what I was trying to say is not clear. Thanks for sticking anyways!